# Error - "#include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>" while compiling g++ file

Tags: c++, g++

I'm quite new to Linux programming.
I'm compiling a simple C++ code using `g++`:

```
#include“recip.hpp”
#include<cassert>

double recip (int i) {
// I should be non-zero.
assert (i != 0);
return 1.0/i;
}
```

The file `recip.hpp` exists in my current directory. I don't understand why I'm getting an error:

```
recip.cpp:1:9: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Because you're using `“` instead of standard double quotes `"` .

Comment: My teacher always put stuff in formatted word documents. It was annoying.

Comment: @chris leave that teacher **now**.

Comment: @H2CO3, He's not bad. That was just an annoying habit of his. It wasn't so much code as diagrams that should have been evenly spaced. Besides, I'm already done the only real programming course our school offers.

Comment: I cannot believe that anyone would edit code in Word, it's just so wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The compiler is not a text editor, nor a human - it checks for exact character code match, not for visual similarity... You have to use

```
#include "recip.hpp"
```

using the standard double quotation marks.

Answer (score 3):

Your first line, treated as UTF-8, reads:

```
0x23 = U+0023
0x69 = U+0069
0x6E = U+006E
0x63 = U+0063
0x6C = U+006C
0x75 = U+0075
0x64 = U+0064
0x65 = U+0065
0xE2 0x80 0x9C = U+201C
0x72 = U+0072
0x65 = U+0065
0x63 = U+0063
0x69 = U+0069
0x70 = U+0070
0x2E = U+002E
0x68 = U+0068
0x70 = U+0070
0x70 = U+0070
0xE2 0x80 0x9D = U+201D
0x0A = U+000A
```

The U+201C and U+201D need to be replaced by U+0022 (ASCII 34), or `"`.

MS Word and other word processors make bad editors for C code.

Answer (score 1):

start swig 
when wei build example.i.

example_wrap.c:2948:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or

```
/* File: example.i */
%module example
%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include 'example.h'
%}
int fact(int n);
```

we change code :

```
/* File: example.i */
%module example

%{ 
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "example.h"
%}
int fact(int n);
```

it is just in include 'double quote'.